# How to change a variable's value multiple times in same function?

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the variable `$score`'s value according to its `$total_votes` score.  The code now (when I `echo $score`) produces a value of 1, every time I run through the function.  It's making me believe that the `$score = $score+1` is not working properly, is there a structure in the code that i'm overlooking?

```
public function score($datediff,$total_votes){
    $score = 0;
    if ($total_votes < 10)                            { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes > 10 && $total_votes < 100 )     { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes > 100 && $total_votes < 1000 )   { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes > 1000 && $total_votes < 10000 ) { $score = $score+1;}

    echo $score.' ';
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public function score($datediff,$total_votes){
    $score = 0;
    if ($total_votes > 0)       { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes > 10)      { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes > 100)     { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes > 1000 && $total_votes <= 10000 ){
        $score = $score+1;
    }

    echo $score.' ';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note : Before referring to this answer please read the comments

As far as what you replied to my comment what I got is you want to add up like this..

```
public function score($datediff,$total_votes){
            $score = 0;
            if ($total_votes < 10)                              { $score = $score+1;}
            if ($total_votes > 10 && $total_votes < 100 )       { $score = $score+2;}
            if ($total_votes > 100 && $total_votes < 1000 )     { $score = $score+3;}
            if ($total_votes > 1000 && $total_votes < 10000 )   { $score = $score+4;}

            echo $score.' ';
            }
```

You need to change the values what you are adding to your variable `$score`

Say for example your total votes are 1500, none of the condition satisfies except the last condition and hence the +1's you are trying to add in each condition won't execute as the condition is not satisfied, php skips to other and finally it add's the value to `$score` in the last condition, so if you want that +4 should be added to your `$score` if the `$total_votes` is **>1000** and **< 10000** than you should add +4 to your `$score` variable in the last condition

Comment: I think +1. +2, etc is my best bet, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions are mutually exclusive. You can't have

```
$total_votes < 10
```

and at the same time

```
$total_votes > 10 && $total_votes < 100
```

since the variable can't be < 10 and > 10 at the same time. Thus $score cannot be incremtented more than once. What you are looking for was probably

```
public function score($datediff,$total_votes){
    $score = 1;

    if ($total_votes > 10)
        $score++;
    if ($total_votes > 100)
        $score++;
    if ($total_votes > 1000)
        $score++;
    if ($total_votes > 10000)
        $score++;
}
```

Note that functions actually compute a rough version of the logarithm base 10 :

```
$score = floor(log10($total_votes))
```

Comment: I need values between 10 and 100 to add a point. Values between 100 and 1000 to add an additional point

Comment: That's what it does. "Additionnal point" for values between 100 and 1000 is "additionnal" because you want to give it a point for being above 10 and additionnaly give a point for being above 100. If you are not convinced, you may want to say the things like that "between 0 and 10, I give 1 point, between 10 and 100 I give 2 points" and so on.

Comment: @DanielFein This does exactly what (I think) you want. A value between [1, 10) will give you a score of 2. A value between between [10, 100) will give you a score of 3, u.s.w.

Comment: The problem here in your formulation, is that the second point is not only given for being between 100 and 1000 but also for being between 1000 and 10000. Thus, it's simpler to say that this second point is given for being above 100.

Comment: I solved my dilemma, but could you explain what you meant by: floor(log10($total_votes))

Comment: I'm not sure you really understood what was the problem since you are still asking questions about how assignements are done. The log10 functions gave you roughly the number of digits of your number in base 10, plus one. This does what you want since between 0 and 10, the numbers have one digit. Between 10 and 100 they have two digits. Thus, it's exactly what you are computing. Except that it's a floating point value which need to be rounded down, and that's what floor does.

Comment: There are two minor differences. One is that using log10 will result in scores smaller than the ones the OP is giving by 1. Two is that the OP caps it at 10000.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements are mutually exclusive. When one condition is true, outhers are false.

Comment: They need to run one after another, not simultaneously.  The score can get up to 4 points the way they run. If total_votes is between 1000 and 10000 then score gets 4 points by each if statement adding one.

Comment: @Daniel Fein No, the way you have it $score will never be > 1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `STATIC` keyword..

```
public function score($datediff,$total_votes){
            static $score = 0;
            if ($total_votes < 10)                              { $score = $score+1;}
            if ($total_votes > 10 && $total_votes < 100 )       { $score = $score+1;}
            if ($total_votes > 100 && $total_votes < 1000 )     { $score = $score+1;}
            if ($total_votes > 1000 && $total_votes < 10000 )   { $score = $score+1;}

            echo $score.' ';
            }
```

It will initialize `$score` only in first call of function.

Also take a look at [**Variable Scope**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: From the comments the OP is posting, I don't think this solves his problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function score($total_votes){
    $score = 0;

    if ($total_votes < 10)     { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes < 100 )   { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes < 1000 )  { $score = $score+1;}
    if ($total_votes < 10000 ) { $score = $score+1;}

    echo $score.' ';
}
```

`$datediff` is extraneous.

Answer (score -1):

First of all your variable $score must be either global or in session.

Second you should use else if statements so that it goes in one condition only.

As per your coding you set $score = 0 each time this function calls so define it outside the function and change the value and see your answer

**Note:** Do not reset this in the function